# Can't realloc character string in C

Tags: c, heap-memory, realloc

I'm having some issues with `realloc`, for example, this code

```
    char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*17);
    s = "bruhbruhlmaolmao";
    s = (char*)realloc(s, sizeof(char)*18);
    if(s == NULL) printf("Memory allocation failed");
    else printf("%s\n",s);
```

I'm trying to reallocate the memory chunk that s is pointing at to a larger memory location in the heap.

I've compiled it and the compiler returns no warning. When I run the executable, It prints out nothing. I hope you can explain to me why and how to fix it

Comment: `s = "bruhbruhlmaolmao";` "throws away" the memory you just allocated and instead points the pointer at a string literal. And you cannot `realloc` a string literal

Comment: C doesn't let you copy an array with a single assignment statement.  You can use a loop or one of the functions in string.h.

Comment: `s = "bruhbruhlmaolmao";` should be `strcpy(s, "bruhbruhlmaolmao");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently I made a dumb decision by assigning `s` to a string: `s = "bruhbruhlmaolmao";`, what I should really do is use something in `string.h` library like `strcpy`